# Go - Correct way of using pgtypes

Tags: go, libpq, pgx, sqlc

I am developing a simple `Go` service to connect to a database for basic querying. I am using `sqlc` to generate the `Go` functions to interact with the DB. when switching the driver from `lib/pq` to `pgx/v5` now the types for the DB fields are `pgtypes` instead of `Go` types. Here's an example:

Instead of this:

```
    type ListAccountsParams struct {
        Owner  string `json:"owner"`
        Limit  int32  `json:"limit"`
        Offset int32  `json:"offset"`
    }
```

I now get this:

```
    type ListAccountsParams struct {
        Owner  pgtype.Text `json:"owner"`
        Limit  pgtype.Int4 `json:"limit"`
        Offset pgtype.Int4 `json:"offset"`
    }
```

However the only way I find of using `pgtypes` is this one:

```
    owner := pgtype.Text{
        String: "Craigs List",
        Valid: true,
    }
```

Instead of just doing `owner := "Craigs List"`. For numeric types is even more overkill, all implementations I find are like this:

```
    pgtype.Numeric{
    Int: big.NewInt(-543), 
    Exp: 3, 
    Status: pgtype.Present
    }
```

Using `sqlc` config file I can just override these types in favor of `Go` standard types, but it makes no sense to me having to override a postgres `text` type to `string` and so on...

It seems to me that this is not the best way of using these types, it is counter intuitive for me. So my question is, am I doing it right? Is there a different way? Ultimately, is there a way to configure `sqlc` to use `Go` types instead of `pgtypes` while still using the `pgx/v5` driver?

Comment: you may need to handle the conversion between Go types and `pgtype` types manually in your code and it means you would need to convert the Go types to the corresponding `pgtype` types before passing them to the generated functions, and vice versa when retrieving values from the database!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can edit `sqlc` configuration file to specify custom types for the fields you want to use Go types instead of `pgtype` types and override the types by specifying the desired Go type in the `sqlc.yaml` file

```
types:
  - name: ListAccountsParams
    fields:
      - name: Owner
        goType: string
      - name: Limit
        goType: int32
      - name: Offset
        goType: int32
```

and please note that using Go types directly may result in potential type mismatches or other issues when interacting with the database,and `pgtype` types are specifically designed to handle PostgreSQL-specific data types and provide a level of type safety and compatibility!

**UPDATE**

according to your comment,when using `pgx/v5` driver with `sqlc`, the generated code uses `pgtype` types to handle PostgreSQL-specific data type and it is the default behavior of `sqlc` when working with the `pgx/v5` driver, and the way you described using `pgtype` types, such as `pgtype.Text` and `pgtype.Int4`, is the correct way of working with those types, for example, when dealing with the `pgtype.Text` type, you need to set the `String` field to the desired value and set the `Valid` field to `true`.

and regarding numeric types, the `pgtype.Numeric` type requires the `Int`, `Exp`, and `Status` fields to be set,it is because the `pgtype.Numeric` type represents a numeric value as an arbitrary-precision integer (`Int`), an exponent (`Exp`), and a status (`Status`) indicating if the value is present or null!

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but overriding is what I want to avoid. I have no issues using `pgtypes` as long I am doing it the right way. However it seems weird to me having to define numeric values the way I described before. Is that the only way? Is there a better, commonly-used way that I am missing? I am asking all these questions because I cannot find any reference online.

Comment: @KarlsMaranjs I updated my answer, and unfortunately, there is no commonly used alternative way to handle these `pgtype` types,the `pgtype` package provides the necessary types and methods to work with PostgreSQL-specific data types in a type-safe manner, and if you find the usage of `pgtype` types to be cumbersome, one possible approach is to write helper functions or methods to simplify the process of creating and working with `pgtype` types,for example, you could create a function that takes a string and returns a `pgtype.Text` type with the `Valid` field set to `true`!

Comment: Ok, I guess that's what I'll do. Thanks.